# Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on null

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I keep getting the following error:

> **Fatal error:** Call to a member function execute() on null in /home/***[sitename]***/public_html/fc/includes/class_db_handle.php on line 130

This is from the u-Auctions script and I honestly am extremely noob to PDO
please help in "DUMMIE TERMS".

```
if (!defined('InuAuctions')) exit('Access denied');

class db_handle 

{

    // database

    private     $pdo;

    private     $DBPrefix;

    private     $CHARSET;

    private     $lastquery;

    private     $fetchquery;

    private     $error;

    public      $PDOerror;



    public function connect($DbHost, $DbUser, $DbPassword, $DbDatabase, $DBPrefix, $CHARSET)

    {

        $this->DBPrefix = $DBPrefix;

        $this->CHARSET = $CHARSET;

        try {

            // MySQL with PDO_MYSQL

            $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$DbHost;dbname=$DbDatabase;charset =$CHARSET", $DbUser, $DbPassword);


            // set error reporting up

            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            // actually use prepared statements

            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

        }

        catch(PDOException $e) {

            $this->trigger_error($e->getMessage());

        }

    }



    // to run a direct query

    public function direct_query($query)

    {

        try {

            $this->lastquery = $this->pdo->query($query);

        }

        catch(PDOException $e) {

            $this->trigger_error($e->getMessage());

        }

    }



    // put together the quert ready for running

    /*

    $query must be given like SELECT * FROM table WHERE this = :that AND where = :here

    then $params would holds the values for :that and :here, $table would hold the vlue for :table

    $params = array(

        array(':that', 'that value', PDO::PARAM_STR),

        array(':here', 'here value', PDO::PARAM_INT),

    );

    last value can be left blank more info http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

    */

    public function query($query, $params = array())

    {

        try {

            //$query = $this->build_query($query, $table);

            $params = $this->build_params($params);

            $params = $this->clean_params($query, $params);

            $this->lastquery = $this->pdo->prepare($query);

            //$this->lastquery->bindParam(':table', $this->DBPrefix . $table, PDO::PARAM_STR); // must always be set

            foreach ($params as $val)

            {

                $this->lastquery->bindParam($val[0], $val[1], @$val[2], @$val[3], @$val[4]);

            }

            $this->lasta->execute();

            //$this->lastquery->debugDumpParams();

        }

        catch(PDOException $e) {

            //$this->lastquery->debugDumpParams();

            $this->trigger_error($e->getMessage());

        }



        //$this->lastquery->rowCount(); // rows affected

    }



    // put together the quert ready for running

    public function fetch($method = 'FETCH_ASSOC')

    {

        try {

            // set fetchquery

            if ($this->fetchquery == NULL)

            {

                $this->fetchquery = $this->lastquery;

            }

            if ($method == 'FETCH_ASSOC') $result = $this->fetchquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if ($method == 'FETCH_BOTH') $result = $this->fetchquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

            if ($method == 'FETCH_NUM') $result = $this->fetchquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

            // clear fetch query

            if ($result == false)

            {

                $this->fetchquery = NULL;

            }

            return $result;

        }

        catch(PDOException $e) {

            $this->trigger_error($e->getMessage());

        }

    }



    // put together the quert ready for running + get all results

    public function fetchall($method = 'FETCH_ASSOC')

    {

        try {

            // set fetchquery

            if ($this->fetchquery == NULL)

            {

                $this->fetchquery = $this->lastquery;

            }

            if ($method == 'FETCH_ASSOC') $result = $this->fetchquery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if ($method == 'FETCH_BOTH') $result = $this->fetchquery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

            if ($method == 'FETCH_NUM') $result = $this->fetchquery->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

            // clear fetch query

            if ($result == false)

            {

                $this->fetchquery = NULL;

            }

            return $result;

        }

        catch(PDOException $e) {

            $this->trigger_error($e->getMessage());

        }

    }



    public function result($column = NULL)

    {

        $data = $this->lastquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

        if (empty($column) || $column == NULL)

        {

            return $data;

        }

        else

        {

            return $data[$column];

        }

    }



    public function numrows()

    {

        try {

            return $this->lastquery->rowCount();

        }

        catch(PDOException $e) {

            $this->trigger_error($e->getMessage());

        }

    }



    public function lastInsertId()

    {

        try {

            return $this->pdo->lastInsertId();

        }

        catch(PDOException $e) {

            $this->trigger_error($e->getMessage());

        }

    }



    private function clean_params($query, $params)

    {

        // find the vars set in the query

        preg_match_all("(:[a-zA-Z_]+)", $query, $set_params);

        //print_r("params" . $query);

        //print_r($params);

        //print_r("set_params");

        //print_r($set_params);

        $new_params = array();

        foreach ($set_params[0] as $val)

        {

            $key = $this->find_key($params, $val);

            $new_params[] = $params[$key];

        }

        //print_r("new_params");

        //print_r($new_params);

        return $new_params;

    }



    private function find_key($params, $val)

    {

        foreach ($params as $k => $v)

        {

            if ($v[0] == $val)

                return $k;

        }

    }



    private function build_params($params)

    {

        $PDO_constants = array(

            'int' => PDO::PARAM_INT,

            'str' => PDO::PARAM_STR,

            'bool' => PDO::PARAM_BOOL,

            'float' => PDO::PARAM_STR

            );

        // set PDO values to params

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($params); $i++)

        {

            // force float

            if ($params[$i][2] == 'float')

            {

                $params[$i][1] = floatval($params[$i][1]);

            }

            $params[$i][2] = $PDO_constants[$params[$i][2]];

        }

        return $params;

    }



    private function trigger_error($error)

    {



        // DO SOMETHING

        //$this->error = $error;

        $this->PDOerror = $error;

    }



    // close everything down

    public function __destruct()

    {

        // close database connection

        $this->pdo = null;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `$this->lasta->execute();` but you have no field `lasta`

Try this

```
$this->lastquery->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks but still doesnt work :'( I get an 

I get an Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053

Comment: I have no idea man, this script is written by u-Auctions and they do not have a fix on there website in the forums. I search everywhere. You can download it at http://sourceforge.net/projects/auctions/  And NO SUPPORT ON THEIR WEBSITE :'(

Answer (score 0):

I would try *extending* the `db_handle` class and modifying/creating some methods like so:

```
<?php
// Make sure the db_handle is included and loaded before hand so it can be extended
class QueryEngine extends db_handle
    {
        private $bind;

        public function connect($host, $username, $password, $database)
            {
                // One note, I removed:
                // $this->DBPrefix = $DBPrefix;
                // $this->CHARSET = $CHARSET;
                // You can add those back in if you want

                try {
                    // Create connection
                    $opts   =   array(  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                                        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                                        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $this->pdo  =   new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $username, $password,$opts);
                }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
            }

        public function query($query, $params = false)
            {
                if(!empty($params))
                    $this->bindVals($params);

                try {
                        if(!empty($this->bind)) {
                                $this->lastquery = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
                                $this->lastquery->execute($this->bind);
                            }
                        else
                            $this->lastquery = $this->pdo->query($query);
                    }
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }

                return $this;
            }

        public  function fetch()
            {
                while($row = $this->lastquery->fetch())
                    $result[]   =   $row;

                return (!empty($result))? $result : 0;
            }

        private function bindVals($params = false)
            {
                $this->bind =   false;

                if(empty($params) || !is_array($params))
                    return $this;

                $i = 0;
                foreach($params as $values) {
                        $this->bind[':'.$i] =   $values;
                        $i++;
                    }

                return $this;
            }
    }
```

**To use our new class:**

```
$dbEngine   =   new QueryEngine();
$dbEngine->connect($host,$username,$password,$database);
print_r($dbEngine->query("select * from users where ID = :0",array("1"))->fetch());
```

This would give you something like *(in my db obviously, the table and columns will be different for you)*:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [unique_id] => 20150203190700523616
            [username] => tester
            [password] => $2a$12$xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            [first_name] => Ras
            [last_name] => Clatt
            [email] => ras@clatt.com
            [usergroup] => 3
            [user_status] => on
            [reset_password] => $2y$10$xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            [timestamp] => 2015-09-25 08:35:09
        )

)
```

This class library you are using is similar to mine so what I have added is parts of the class I use. I tested this extended class out and it works with my database, so hopefully it works with yours!